# Javascript searching made easy

Tags: javascript, arrays

> See Katana314's answer below

After spending days to figure out how to use regex for BBcode translation I have decided to reinvent the wheel and here I am.

I wrote a script that search for BBcode tags like [b][/b] or any other [] in the text.

I'm looking for an easy solution to compare the tags I found in the text and match them with a table, "array" if you prefer. I want to do it like that because eventually I will use a database to insert and remove BBcodes.

I kinda like the way I do the replacement cause its easy to populate. and there is no need for a Regex.

**The replace fonction with it's array:**

```
 function bbToHtml(s) {
        var p, pairs = [
                 { "in": "[b]", "out": '<span style="color:red;">' },
                 { "in": "[/b]", "out": '</span>' },
              ];
        for (p in pairs) {
            s = s.replace(pairs[p]["in"], pairs[p]["out"]);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Now that's fairly simple. What i would like to do is to compare my BBcode with the "in" values.

Lets say i have var `BBCode = "[we]";`

How do i proceed to see if it matchs one of my array value;

If the result is true then i can just do `bbToHtml(BBCode);` and if not i skip it or trow an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love ES5 array functions.

```
function isBB(str) {
  return !pairs.every(function(s) {
    return s.in !== str;
  });
}
```

`every` means "return true if this function returns true for all values of this array." This is assuming you are only looking for `"[b]"` and not `"[b] "` or any slight variation.

Answer (score -1):

possible solution to your question:

```
 var pairs = [
             { "in": "[b]", "out": '<span style="color:red;">' },
             { "in": "[/b]", "out": '</span>' },
          ];

 function bbToHtml(s) 
 {
    for (var p in pairs) {
        s = s.replace(pairs[p]["in"], pairs[p]["out"]);
    }
    return s;
}
var search = '[we]';

if (pairs[search]) bbToHtml(search);
```